# c#: how to match a variable string followed by a space and currency and pull the currency?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match the following cases and pull the number value:

```
"b 30.00"
"bill 30.00"
"bill 30"
"b 30"
```

I've tried:

```
var regex = new Regex("^b(?-i:ill)?$ ^$?d+(.d{2})?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However, this doesn't seem to return a match, and I'm not sure how to pull the digit.

Comment: What's expected result exactly?

Comment: I want to get the currency value. so I should get `30.00 or 30` but I need to match the "b" or "bill" as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't well understand how to use anchors `^` & `$`, read about this.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[Bb](?:ill)? \d+(?:\.\d{2})?$");
```

or better since you only need ascii digits (and not all possible digits of the world):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[Bb](?:ill)? [0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$");
```

If you want to figure a literal `.` you must escape it *(same thing for a literal `$`)*. Note the use of a verbatim string to avoid double backslashes.

Feel free to add capture groups around what you want to capture.

Comment: What's that `@` in the beginning of your pattern? *(before delimiter)*

Comment: @Shafizadeh: it indicates that the string is a verbatim string. (a raw string in C# world, no need to use double escape inside.)

Comment: I get unrecognized escape sequence

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention if RegEx is actually required to accomplish your goal. If RegEx is not required, and you know that your string is in a specific format, you could just split the string:

```
string val = "bill 30.00";
string[] split = val.Split(' ');

string name = string.Empty;
decimal currency = 0m;
if (split.Length > 1)
{
    name = split[0];
    decimal.TryParse(split[1], out currency);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

new Regex (@"\b\d+(.\d {2})*") should give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

Just try the code

string Value = "bill 30.00";
 string resultString = Regex.Match(Value, @"\d+").Value;